# JSON to PHP array issue

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have tried to use PHP decode  to parse my JSON string below into an array so I can extract the current and day for both channels from the file.

my json file owl_output.json looks like..

```
{"channels":{"0":[{"current":1288,"units":"w"},{"day":31278.57,"units":"wh"}],"1":    [{"current":660,"units":"w"},{"day":9191.11,"units":"wh"}]}}
```

I'am only ever getting one result displayed, the php code I have managed to get working is below

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('owl_output.json');
$data = json_decode($string,true);
print_r($json);
foreach ($data['channels']['0'] as $data)
{
    echo $data ['current'];
}
?>
```

This only display the current for channel 0.  If I try to add additional fields it doesn't display

echo $data ['current']['day']; ( doesn't work )

Can someone advise how I can display current and day for both channels 0 & 1 ?

My aim is to display this in a html page at the end and to keep polling the json file?

The array it displays is below

```
Array
(
    [channels] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [current] => 1288
                            [units] => w
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => 31278.57
                            [units] => wh
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [current] => 660
                            [units] => w
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => 9191.11
                            [units] => wh
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Can anyone offer any assistance with this ?

Thanks

Comment: You should loop over `$data['channels']`, not `$data['channels'][0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflict on `$data` reference in loop and bad array indexes :

```
foreach ($data['channels'] as $channel)
{
    echo $channel[0]['current'];
    echo $channel[1]['day'];
}
```

Comment: This has worked, however I would like to display all the results on a new line for each result. Currently this displays to the screen as one long line.

Comment: If you use html output, use tags for formating, as `<br>`, if output is in raw text, use `"\n"` to go to new line.

Comment: thanks again that has worked. If I wanted to poll the owl_output.js file. where should the call go in the code ?                          <?php
$string = file_get_contents('test/owl_output.js');
$data = json_decode($string,true);
print_r($json);
foreach ($data['channels'] as $channel)
{
    echo "Current " . $channel[0]['current']. "<br>";

    echo "Day " . $channel[1]['day'].  "<br>";
}
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("test/owl_output.js", function(data) {
        // update the view with your fresh data
    });
}, 5000);
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

The variable $data is conflicting:

Used to store the data, and used in the foreach loop. Rename the $data variable in the foreach for example:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('owl_output.json');
$data = json_decode($string,true);
print_r($json);
foreach ($data['channels'] as $channel)
{
    echo $channel[0]['current'];
    echo $channel[1]['day'];
}
?>
```

I did edit since there was an other error because there is not 'current' in every record.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data['channels'] as $chanel)
{
    echo $chanel[0]['current'];
    echo $chanel[1]['day'];
}
```